# Include PHP FORM in SQL Content

Tags: php, sql, forms, include

I Use SQL to store pages of my site & Admin can edit the content of pages
for some pages like enquiry,contact I need to use PHP Forms in Page Content

What I want is page.php?name=contact get data from sql of page name 'contact' which Admin can edit

e.g. Data is:

```
"Address of Company"
"Use the form below to contact us"
```

& Below that data I want to include content from contact.php file which include form & all the validation and mail sending function.

Can I use some shortcode or function like wordpress [contact-form] which can be included in sql data so while accessing page.php?name=contact include content from contact.php file below the data of sql.

```
"Address of Company"
"Use the form below to contact us"
[contact-form]<--- Form from contact.php or enquiry.php included below content
```

Whats the method to use this type of file include

Thanks

Comment: @YourCommonSense Gud Answer :D

Comment: @Andy M using separate php files containing huge code & validations etc. path mysitecom/contact.php & mysitecom/enquiry.php 
While other pages structure like this mysitecom/page.php?name=about so I want to include contact.php enquiry.php in tune with site structure mysitecom/page.php?name=contact 

also client/admin able to edit text on top of form which is saved in sql

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to include a file depending upon a value of a GET variable? And you want a short code for it. Am i getting it right?

Comment: what's the point in including contact.php into page.php btw?

Comment: @itachi I want to save some page content in sql alongwith shortcode 
so when that page is called sql page content is displayed and shortcode stored in sql at the end of content automatically call PHP FORM associated with that code Like we do in wordpress.
e.g. text [contact-form] added in page content sql automatically called content from PHP file contact.php below that page content.

Comment: @YourCommonSense as replied earlier to Andy: **1)** Entire site structure is page.php?name=about so I want to make all pages structure similar instead of mysite.com/contact.php mysite.php?name=contact
**2)** Admin/Client can edit/change text details above forms & Its not good to provide entire form with code for edit to client so I want to automatically include form & coding part below the editable text.

Comment: 1) well, why not to make entire site structure just like `/about.php`? it looks way more neat and easier to implement. 2) I don't understand that part. What does it do with page.php?name=about structure? It seems you are just do not understand the difference between the content, the code and the template, mixing them into one messy salad.

Comment: let me ask this, how many view files you have? why you don't include the form in view file instead of going through all these hassle?

Comment: @YourCommonSense To query pages from SQL I use page.php?name=about or it can be page.php?id=1  So How can I get page structure like /about.php from this?

Same Shortcode include into content technique used in Wordpress so they doing it without any understanding :/

Comment: I don't know about others but from my perspective, wordpress shouldn't be an ideal app to set the standards. Its codes are messy. Its popular that's a different issue.

Comment: you shouldn't store your php code in the database.

Comment: @itachi View file U mean separate PHP file ? main object is to store form's description text in sql which admin/client can edit and want to include PHP code and Form automatically below that page without adding that huge Form code in sql and client cnt edit/interfere with that coding part.Thats It

since I used many times wordpress system shortcode used in content that include form automatically so I though there can be some function to make shortcode. Using Shortcode is not essential I just gave example Any other workaround for such situation?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yup I dnt want to include all huge form code in sql
thats why want to include automatic that php form file part below page

Comment: I still am not getting what you are trying to achieve but here's a suggestion from the part i understood. You can make a seperate file with the form (if needed, make two different files for client and admin with appropriate priviledge.) then make an ajax call on click event and load the form in a div. Can it fulfill your goal?

Answer (score -2):

You must do the steps below:

1. use `$name = $_GET['name'];` to detect the current page.
2. Include your PHP file using `include($name.'.php');`.
3. Use MySQL functions like `mysql_query()` to load what is related to your current page and show it in your page. (This should be in contact.php source codes).

Wordpress short-codes are not accessible everywhere ... They work just for Wordpress itself.

Comment: yea I know wordpress shortcode not availble in other scripts just gav example that I want Like this :D

hmmmmmm UR name include solution can work in such case

Comment: @Vehlad sure it will work. As a most simple and straight way to hack your site

Comment: not to mention that this piece of text doesn;t answer the question at all

Comment: @YourCommonSense Its not answer to question 
but still perfect workaround till get answer from someone as my question is far above the stackoveflow folks knowledge :P